# Parent element does not follow child img dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css

If we have this `HTML` structure:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

and we follow that with this CSS declaration:

```
#wrap {
  height:200px;
}

.image-wrap {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

on initial load the `.image-wrap` element will be exactly the same size as the `img`
but after we use JavaScript to manipulate the height like this:

```
document.getElementById('wrap').style.height = '100px';
```

the `.image-wrap` and the `img` will follow, changing their height to `100px`. The `img` will change it's `width` based on its' own natural aspect ratio but the `.image-wrap`s' `width` will remain the same as on initial load. If you try to debug this in the developer tools, once you "touch" the `height` on either the `.image-wrap` or the `img`, the `.image-wrap` will change it's width to mach that of the `img`...

Any idea how to make the `.image-wrap` follow the `img`?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0aLx2xz7/7/

**edit:**
Doesn't happen in FF and Safari, happens on Android and Chrome

Comment: I can't even reproduce the issue in the fiddle. Oh I see the issue in chrome but not FF

Comment: Maybe it's just a chrome bug?

Answer (score 1):

Set display inline to the image wrapper. I am not sure if this is some kind display error or just chrome being buggy but setting display to inline fixes it. Actually you can set display to block as well and it appears to go away. Looks like some kind of a bug to me, it doesn't even appear on Safari

https://jsfiddle.net/0aLx2xz7/3/

```
#image-wrap {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;    
    border: 2px solid red; // for illustration
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's still the same. It's fixed at the moment you edit the attribute in the developer tools but on page load nothing changes. Might be a chrome bug?

Comment: Could be but I don't see how this affects actual use of the site and it seems this is a new issue from what you described in the question. Or did I misunderstand it

Comment: Well it looks bad when the border has different size than the picture. Affects just the aesthetics.

Comment: @Dave but is this only for dev tools? I understood it as on initial load, the red box is bigger than it should be. Is this not what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue. The red box should be the size of the image after the JS adjusts the height.

Comment: @Dave but the red box is the same height as the image on load in the fiddle, is it not?

Comment: Yes but the width of the `.image-wrap` (red box) is not.

Comment: @Dave but in the fiddle the width and height of the red box is the same as the image on load

Comment: Awesome, setting to inline fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height of the image, you need to change the behavior of the wrappers.

```css
#wrap {

}
#image-wrap {
   width: auto;
   border: 2px solid red; // for illustration
   display: inline-block;
}
img {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
}
```

In this code the `img` will define the width and height of its parent. The main `image-wrap` div's display has changed to `inline-block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/0aLx2xz7/5/

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I need to be setting the height on the `#wrap` as I want to have more images in it. One work around could be setting height on all `img`s with a `for` loop... but maybe someone comes up with a better way...

Comment: @Dave Does it need to have an initial height and grow with the images?

Comment: I calculate the height based on screen size. The images need to follow the calculated height and the wrappers need to follow the images.